# Gwt - label receives all events

Tags: html, gwt

I have a tooltip label near the cursor.
I have 2 problems which i am not sure how to fix:

1. When the mouse is above the label the cursor changes to text cursor. I want the cursor to not change.
2. The Canvas element does not receive any mouse event. It seems that the label receives the events.

How it can be fixed?

Comment: There are two very different questions here. You may consider splitting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor should not change over a label. Something wrong with your CSS: check in your browser which style has "cursor" in it.

If you don't feel like figuring it out, just set style "cursor: default" on your label (you may need to add !important; if it does not work.